# xslt code to generate an element in the target even it is coming multiple times from source under for loop?

Tags: xslt-3.0

sample payload for testing :

```
    <n0:MT_SalesOrder_Resp_SAP xmlns:n0="http://eaton.com/pi/api/SalesOrderInquiry" xmlns:prx="urn:sap.com:proxy:D47:/1SAI/TASDA80D4E368BF1C227C5D:740" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <salesorders>
        <salesorder>
          <orderNumber>0213961849</orderNumber>
          <addresses>
            <address>
              <addressIdentifier>AG</addressIdentifier>
              <documentNumber>0213961849</documentNumber>
              <lineNumber>000000</lineNumber>
              <number>0000320101</number>
              <name>Shenzhen Diwei Video Co., Ltd.U</name>
            </address>
            <address>
              <addressIdentifier>RE</addressIdentifier>
              <documentNumber>0213961849</documentNumber>
              <lineNumber>000000</lineNumber>
              <number>0000320101</number>
              <name>Shenzhen Diwei Video Co., Ltd.U</name>
             </address>
            <address>
              <addressIdentifier>RG</addressIdentifier>
              <documentNumber>0213961849</documentNumber>
              <lineNumber>000000</lineNumber>
              <number>0000320101</number>
              <name>Shenzhen Diwei Video Co., Ltd.U</name>
            </address>
            <address>
              <addressIdentifier>WE</addressIdentifier>
              <documentNumber>0213961849</documentNumber>
              <lineNumber>000000</lineNumber>
              <number>0000320101</number>
              <name>Shenzhen Diwei Video Co., Ltd.U</name>
             </address>
            <address>
              <addressIdentifier>WE</addressIdentifier>
              <documentNumber>0213961849</documentNumber>
              <lineNumber>000000</lineNumber>
              <number>0000320101</number>
              <name>深圳迪威影像有限公司XXXX</name>
             </address>
            <address>
              <addressIdentifier>Z5</addressIdentifier>
              <documentNumber>0213961849</documentNumber>
              <lineNumber>000000</lineNumber>
              <number>0900000740</number>
              <name>张三</name>
            </address>
            <address>
              <addressIdentifier>PLANT</addressIdentifier>
              <documentNumber>0213961849</documentNumber>
              <lineNumber>000010</lineNumber>
              <number>5567</number>
              <name>BA1 Trade, SZ (PQ)</name>
            </address>
            <address>
              <addressIdentifier>SHIPFROM</addressIdentifier>
              <documentNumber>0213961849</documentNumber>
              <lineNumber>000010</lineNumber>
              <number>5567</number>
              <name>SANTAK ELECTRONIC (SHEN ZHEN) CO.,LTD</name>
            </address>
            <address>
              <addressIdentifier>PLANT</addressIdentifier>
              <documentNumber>0213961849</documentNumber>
              <lineNumber>000020</lineNumber>
              <number>5567</number>
              <name>BA1 Trade, SZ (PQ)</name>
            </address>
            <address>
              <documentNumber>0213961849</documentNumber>
              <lineNumber>000020</lineNumber>
            </address>
            <address>
              <addressIdentifier>PLANT</addressIdentifier>
              <documentNumber>0213961849</documentNumber>
              <lineNumber>000030</lineNumber>
              <number>5567</number>
              <name>BA1 Trade, SZ (PQ)</name>
            </address>
          </addresses>
        </salesorder>
      </salesorders>
    </n0:MT_SalesOrder_Resp_SAP>
```

xslt code i am using currently kindly requesting to provide some logic to repeat shiptoIdetefier as one time and shipmet address will be multiple times.

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="http://eaton.com/pi/api/SalesOrderInquiry">
 <xsl:template match="/">
     <ns0:MT_SalesOrder_Resp_API>
         <salesorders>
             <xsl:for-each select="/ns0:MT_SalesOrder_Resp_SAP/salesorders/salesorder">
                 <xsl:if test="orderNumber">
                     <salesorder>
                         <orderNumber>
                             <xsl:value-of select="orderNumber"/>
                         </orderNumber>
                         <xsl:variable name="orderNo">
                             <xsl:value-of select="orderNumber"/>
                         </xsl:variable>
                         <xsl:choose>
                             <xsl:when test='orderDate !="" and orderDate != "00000000"'>
                                 <orderDate>
                                     <xsl:value-of select='concat (substring (orderDate, 1, 4 ), "-", substring (orderDate, 5, 2 ), "-", substring (orderDate, 7, 2 ),"T00:00:00.000")'/>
                                 </orderDate>
                             </xsl:when>
                             <xsl:otherwise>
                                 <orderDate/>
                             </xsl:otherwise>
                         </xsl:choose>
                         <xsl:for-each select="addresses/address">
                             <xsl:if test='addressIdentifier="AG" and lineNumber="000000"'>
                                 <customerNumber>
                                     <xsl:value-of select="number"/>
                                 </customerNumber>
                                 <customerAddress>
                                     <name>
                                         <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                                     </name>
                                 </customerAddress>
                             </xsl:if>
                             <xsl:if test='addressIdentifier="RE" and lineNumber="000000"'>
                                 <billToIdentifier>
                                     <xsl:value-of select="number"/>
                                 </billToIdentifier>
                                 <billingAddress>
                                     <name>
                                         <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                                     </name>
                                     </billingAddress>
                             </xsl:if>
                             <xsl:if test='addressIdentifier="WE" and lineNumber="000000"'>
                                 <shipToIdentifier>
                                     <xsl:value-of select="number"/>
                                 </shipToIdentifier>
                                 <shipmentAddress>
                                     <name>
                                         <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                                     </name>
                                 </shipmentAddress>
                             </xsl:if>
                         <xsl:if test='addressIdentifier="Z5" and lineNumber="000000"'>
                                 <salesToEnquery>
                                     <xsl:value-of select="number"/>
                                 </salesToEnquery>
                                 <salesEnquery>
                                     <name>
                                         <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                                     </name>
                                 </salesEnquery>
                             </xsl:if>
                             <xsl:if test='addressIdentifier="AP" and lineNumber="000000"'>
                                 <ShipToContact>
                                     <name>
                                         <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                                     </name>
                                     </ShipToContact>
                             </xsl:if>
                         </xsl:for-each>
                         </salesorder>
                 </xsl:if>
             </xsl:for-each>
         </salesorders>
     </ns0:MT_SalesOrder_Resp_API>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i am expecting shipToIdentifier to be repeated only once in the target but it is coming two times along with the shipment address because the shipToIdentifier is same for both shipment address:

```
    <shipToIdentifier>0000320101</shipToIdentifier>
            <shipmentAddress>
                <name>Shenzhen Diwei Video Co., Ltd.U</name>
                <city>Shenzhen</city>
            </shipmentAddress>
            <shipToIdentifier>0000320101</shipToIdentifier>
            <shipmentAddress>
                <name>深圳迪威影像有限公司XXXX</name>
                <city>深圳南</city>
            </shipmentAddress>
```

Comment: Consider to show minimal but complete samples of both the existing input, the used XSLT code and the wanted and current output, so that we easily reproduce this. Without seeing the input we kind of need to guess where the output data comes from.

Comment: Hi Martin,
i am not able to add complete code due to length restriction. could you please provide some option to send complete code like email etc please.

Comment: No, reduce your real data to a minimal but complete and reproducible example to demonstrate the issue you have, show us all the necessary details in the limits of a StackOverflow question, then we can try to answer it.

Comment: You need a grouping mechanism, which XSLT version?
Please provide a sample of orginal XML document, or reduce all code to a simple case
Please Note: Your expected output has an invalid XML syntax, you need at least an XML root node

Comment: I updaetd the input, xslt code which i am using currently and explained about expected output. Kindly requesting your help. Thanks